# Javascript. Embed or link?

Tags: php, javascript, model-view-controller

I'm starting to get into a lot more JavaScript thanks to a few UI frameworks such as KendoUI and Dojo/Dijit and I'm trying to integrate these with my custom MVC framework.  However, all of their examples have the JavaScript embedded in `<script></script>` tags along with the HTML, which is fine and just means that the code gets dumped in my Views.

I was just wondering if there was some '*standard*' or '*more acceptable*' method of presenting custom JavaScript code in my projects.  Is embedding the code in the HTML the best way to do it, or is it considered *nicer* to store the JavaScript in .js files and link to it from the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a script tag, for example `<script src="foo.js"></script>`

Ideally use a minified version, for example `<script src="foo.min.js"></script>`

If you're building a website, also look into ways of caching the file (and uncaching if the files changes), for example by using a datestamp in the file name.

Some programming frameworks have ways to automatically combine and minify all the JavaScript files for a page. For example, Rails has an asset pipeline that handles this for you.

Comment: You mean script tag with src attribute?  It's annoying that the same tag is used to embed and link to JavaScript.

But thanks, I think I get what you mean.  Next step will be building the minify function into my MVC framework.

Comment: Yes, script tag with src attribute. I'm updating the answer to show it.

Comment: Thanks.  Makes sense.  I completely forgot about the advantages of caching the files.  My MVC framework now minifies thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should use external `<script>` tags to allow the browser to cache the scripts and save bandwidth.

Optionally, you can also automatically minify them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the style I use,

1).I usually link `js libs` ( jQuery and etc.. ) using `<script src="libURL"></script>`

reasons :

1. This caches the js lib. Most of the pages in my site will be
   using that particular js lib and caching will reduce the loading
   time and bandwidth use.
2. Once I got a newer version of the js lib I have to just replace
   the old one with the new. No need to change stuffs page by page!

2).I embed scripts using `<script>//codes here</script>` method when those codes are specific to that particular page.

Reasons:

1. To make sure I will not mess up with my codes! ;-)
2. These codes have more tendency to be changed while updating the site,therefor it's good not to have them cached.(But no use if your site is not under going rapid changes!)